# Find the IP/hostname of the KVM host from VM?

Tags: kvm

I have a KVM hypervisor host and have deployed a few Ubuntu VMs on the same. My question is how do I extract the KVM host IP address(I have multiple hosts on same network and hence can't assume a static IP for the host) from within the deployed VM. In other Hypervisors like Xen, VM ware there are specific files in the VM itself which we can read and find the Host IP. But, so far I have not encountered any such things in KVM. If anyone knows how to go by this problem. please, help me out guys.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Principally, a correct implementation of a Hypervisor will not allow a host to find out this information **without active help**, meaning e.g. VMware tools or similar. This can be visualized by assuming a Hypervisor, that has no host IP, but is managed only through the CLI.

So what you are looking for is "KVM guest tools", which AFAIK do not exist.